# How to correctly mock class with Runnable implements

Tags: java, unit-testing, concurrency, mockito

**Hi!**

I have a class:

```
public class RecovererService {
    private final ConfigServiceProvider serviceProvider;
    private final ErrorRecordRepository recordRepository;
    private final SimpleWriterTest simpleWriterTest;
    private final AuditRecordProcessor itemProcessor;
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;

    private boolean isRunning;

    @Override
    public void startService() {
        if (serviceProvider.isRecoveryServiceAllowed()) {
            log.info("========================== Starting Recoverer process ==========================");
            isRunning = true;
            scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new RecovererThread(recordRepository,
                    simpleWriterTest,
                    itemProcessor),
                    0,
                    5000L,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
```

As a parameter in the singleThreadScheduleExecutor, I pass the following class, which implements the Runnable interface:

```
public class RecovererThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
                deleteFailedRowFromDb("id");
    }

    private AuditRecordDto getFailedRowFromDb(String id) {
        return null;
    }
```

To check the correct operation of the class, I wrote a unit test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RecovererServiceTest {
    private final ConfigServiceProvider serviceProvider = mock(ConfigServiceProvider.class);
    private final ErrorRecordRepository recordRepository = mock(ErrorRecordRepository.class);
    private final SimpleWriterTest simpleWriterTest = mock(SimpleWriterTest.class);
    private final AuditRecordProcessor itemProcessor = mock(AuditRecordProcessor.class);
    private final Runnable recovererThread = mock(Runnable.class);
    ThreadFactory mock = mock(ThreadFactory.class);
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(mock);
    private final RecovererService recovererService = new RecovererService(serviceProvider, recordRepository, simpleWriterTest, itemProcessor);

    @Test
    public void testRecovererServiceStart() {
        doReturn(true).when(serviceProvider).isRecoveryServiceAllowed();
        recovererService.startService();
        verify(recovererThread, timeout(6000)).run();
    }
}
```

But I get an error in the test:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
recovererThread.run();
```

At the same time, in the unit test logs, I see that this method is called

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the `RecovererThread` object instance using `new` in your code:

```
scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new RecovererThread(...))
```

The mock instance in your test (`Runnable recovererThread = mock(Runnable.class)`) is not injected into your actual code. The mock is a separate object, which is not interacted with in any way, so Mockito does not register the call.

To actually verify the call on the mocked thread you would have to pass it to the `RecovererService` and use it there or define a factory class that would be used to create threads (actually Runnables) instead of using `new`. That way you could use a default implementation in the production code and a mocked implementation in the test code.